# An infinite sum of fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find

$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{8} + \frac{9}{32} +\frac{27}{128}+...$

My attempt:-

S= $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{3^{x-1}}{2^{2x-1}}$

= $\sum(\frac{3}{2})^{x-1}\times2^{-x}$

I need a hint for how can i go on ?

Comment: It's a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

Comment: It might be easier to see if you factor  $1/2$ out of every term.

Answer (score 4):

This is a geometric series with common ratio $r=\dfrac{3}{4}$ and first term $a=\dfrac{1}{2}$. Now just use the formula $S_{\infty}=\dfrac{a}{1-r}$.